# Self invoking function that can be called as well

Tags: javascript

The following code works, but I'd like to use the self-invoking function syntax when declaring it instead of calling it explicitly on the last line:

```
var ShowMe = function() {
    if ($('input:checkbox:checked').length) {
        $('#Save').fadeIn('slow');
    } else {
        $('#Save').hide();
    }
};
$('input:checkbox').on('click',ShowMe);
ShowMe();
```

Comment: if you're specifically interested in a function calling itself immediately after it's been declared, that is possible (sort of). I'm assuming what you were really looking for though was what Neal posted?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't declare the `var` inside of an expression, but you can put its definition in one:

```
var ShowMe; (ShowMe = function() {
    if ($('input:checkbox:checked').length) {
        $('#Save').fadeIn('slow');
    } else {
        $('#Save').hide();
    }
})();

$('input:checkbox').on('click',ShowMe);
```

Comment: rot13: I laughed out loud at your profile.  +1 for style points.

Answer (score 2):

Try this instead:

```
var ShowMe = function() {
    if ($(this).length) { // `this` is the input that was clicked
        $('#Save').fadeIn('slow');
    } else {
        $('#Save').hide();
    }
};
$('input:checkbox').on('click', ShowMe).trigger('click');
```

---

### Update based on comments below:

```
$('#Save').hide();
$('input:checkbox').on('click', function() {
    if(this.checked) { //check if this is checked
         $('#Save').show('slow');
    }
    else if(!($('input[type="checkbox"]:checked').length)) { 
            //check to see if anything else was checked 
         $('#Save').hide();
    }
});
```

Comment: Wow.  The solutions are NEVER anything I would have thought of myself.  I'm constantly being surprised by JavaScript.

Comment: Actually, this doesn't work because it checked every checkbox on page load.

Comment: @Pedro haha that is because onclick the checkbox is checked ^_^

Comment: Oh, the ole reverse physiology eh? Initialize them to checked so that they're unchecked...

Comment: Ah, but this would trigger ShowMe for every checkbox on page load.

Comment: When the user tuns on a checkbox, then the save button appears.  The save button is visible if a checkbox is already checked when the page loads.  Your solution works, but would call ShowMe multiple times.

Comment: I think I'm going to give the answer to rot13 because that is a more direct answer to the original question.  Your update has shown that my logic wasn't as optimal as it should be.  But the self-invoking syntax was what I was after to begin with.  Thanks though Neal!